# Showing that $E_k+m_0c^2=mc^2$ (calculus)

Tags: calculus

I got this question on my calculus class:

I'm supposed to show that $$E_k+m_0c^2=mc^2$$
Attempt:
 $$E_k=\int^v_0 \frac{m_0v}{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dv$$

Solving this integral gives me that $$E_k = \frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

I haven't had any physics yet, so how do I possibly show this?

Comment: okay so when $v=0 \rightarrow m=m_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful: your final expression for $E_k$ is one antiderivative of the integrand you tried integrating, but it's not the one that vanishes at $0$, so it's not the actual value of that integral. Fix that. You'll be able to finish the proof then.

Comment: ah, seems like I forgot to add the limits

Comment: hmm i get that $$E_k= \frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}-mc^2$$

Comment: @Samishaft Right, so the final result is equivalent to $m=\cdots$

Comment: huh, I don't think I understand what you're trying to say

Comment: $E_k+mc^2=\frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

Comment: It would mean that I had to know that $\frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}=mc^2$ @J.G

Comment: Never mind. I got it now. Thank you :D